# Is there a way spark won't escape the backslash coming at beginning of each column?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `column` that has `windows address` as follows:

> \aod140med01MediaExtractorCatalog20190820Hub26727007444841620183_6727007462021489387.nmf

After reading it to a `dataset` when I am trying to read the `column` it's escaping the first backslash and printing the value as follows. Is there a way to skip this?

> aod140med01MediaExtractorCatalog20190820Hub26727007444841620183_6727007462021489387.nmf

Comment: are you reading from a csv file? have you tried using escape option to define the escape character

Answer (score 0):

By default Apache spark not removing back slach

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(
     | Seq(
     |   (1,"khan /, vaquar","30","/aod140med01MediaExtractorCatalog20190820Hub26727007444841620183_6727007462021489387.nmf"),
     |   (2,"Zidan /, khan","5","vkhan1MediaExtractorCatalog20190820Hub26727007444841620183_6727007462021489387.nmf"),
     |   (3,"Zerina khan","1","test")
     |   ) ).toDF("id","name","age","string").show
```

[image]

Please share your full code to further debug issue.